# $1/\cos x$ integration

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Question: The aim of this question is to integrate $\frac{1}{\cos x}$
a. Write an integral as $\int \frac{\cos x}{\cos^2(x)}dx$ [DONE]
b. Use $u= \sin x$ [DONE]
c. Use partial fraction to integrate [DONE]
d. Multiply a fraction top and bottom by $1+\sin x$ to simplify it.

My answer to part c is $\frac{\ln(1+\sin x)}{2} - \frac{\ln(1-\sin x)}{2} +c$ but I could not simplify it by multiplyting $1 + \sin x$. Is there a way I could do it?

Comment: Combine the two logs by dividing the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

> You could use this technique,

We can write,
$$\int \sec x dx$$
$$\int  \frac{\sec x(\sec x+\tan x)}{\sec x+\tan x} dx$$
Taking $u=\sec x+\tan x$
$$du=\sec x(\sec x+\tan x)$$

> $$\int \frac{1}{t} dt$$$$\ln |t|$$$$\ln (|\sec x+\tan x|)$$

OR

> $$\ln \Big(\Big|\frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}\Big|\Big)$$
>   Multiplying and dividing by $1+\sin x$
>   $$\ln \Big(\Big|\frac{(1+\sin x)^2}{1-\sin^2 x}\Big|\Big)$$
>   $$\ln \Big(\Big|\frac{(1+\sin x)^2}{\cos^2 x}\Big|\Big)$$
>   $$\ln \Big(\Big|(tan x+\sec x)^2\Big|\Big)$$
>   $$2\ln \Big(\Big|\tan x+\sec x\Big|\Big)$$

Comment: thanks that helps

Answer (score 1):

From your answer in part (c)

$ A =\frac{1}{2} \ln(1+\sin x ) - \frac{1}{2}\ln (1-\sin x) $

$  = \ln (\sqrt{1+\sin x}) - \ln (\sqrt{1-\sin x}) $

$  = \ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\sin x }}{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}\right) $

$= \ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\sin x }{1-\sin x} \cdot \frac{1+\sin x}{1+\sin x}}\right) $

$= \ln\left(\frac{1+\sin x }{\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}}\right)$

$= \ln\left(\frac{1+\sin x }{\cos x}\right)$

$= \ln\left(\sec x + \tan x \right) .$